# 12 volt led powered by 0-10v

Tags: led-strip

I am running 12 x led strips controlled by a 0-10v dimmable controller however the led strips are 12v dc and are not operating at their full output at 10v.  How can I amplify the 0-10v output to produce a 0-12v output to get the full brightness out of the leds?  When I connect the strips to a 12v dc source they operate perfectly but I need to use the programmable 0-10v dimmer to control them.

Comment: Can't you simply use Opamps to do this?  Make it rail to 12V

Comment: It is not a matter of "amplifying" the 0~10V control voltage.  It is a matter of CONTROLLING the LED supply (typically by Pulse Width Modulation PWM) as directed by the 10V control signal.

Answer (score 2):

You need an LED dimming supply which can be controlled by a 10V control signal. 0~10V control signals are a very common way of controlling lamp brightness regardless of whether they operate on low DC voltage (like 12V) or mains-voltages (like 115V or 230V).

Google returned about 721,000 results (in 0.66 seconds) when I searched for: LED dimmer 10V controller

Comment: This is the rigth answer. Unless OP is on a very tight money budget and on a very large time budget, and already has some components around.